# Matplotlib style not working in pandas bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

The code I used to produce the bar plot as per [pandas Visualization  tutorial](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/visualization.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('ggplot')

np.random.seed(123456)
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=ts.index, columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.cumsum()

plt.figure()
df.ix[5].plot(kind='bar'); plt.axhline(0, color='k')
plt.show()
```

I get:

[image: bar plot with matplotlib default colours when ggplot colours expected]

I was expecting to get the bar colours as in the tutorial (vermilion), instead the bars are the default matplotlib blue colour.

I suspect the problem is in pandas. Colours are correct when pandas is not used.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(5)
y1, y2 = np.random.randint(1, 25, size=(2, 5))
width = 0.25
ax.bar(x, y1, width)
ax.bar(x + width, y2, width)
ax.set_xticks(x + width)
ax.set_xticklabels(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

plt.show()
```

I created my environment using conda.

```
In [22]: pd.__version__
Out[22]: u'0.17.1'
```

How can I get pandas plot the right colours?

Comment: well, I don't get the `default matplotlib blue` color when I run your code on my machine.

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? It sounds like [this bug in pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11614), which affects matplotlib 1.5.0.

Comment: Fwiw, I do get a blue bar plot. Mpl 1.5.0, pd 0.17.1. And yes, that bug report looks like your problem. It does show a solution in one of the replies; hope that works for you.

Comment: @ali_m Mpl 1.5.0. Thank you for the link - I found the solution.

Comment: @Dimitri Can you please write up an answer to your own question?

Comment: @tcaswell Done. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As ali_m pointed out in the comments, it is the [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11614) in the latest version of pandas (0.17.1) when using matplotlib version 1.5.0.

The fix will be in the next pandas release.

Until the new release is out, I ran

```
pip install git+git://github.com/pydata/pandas.git@master
```

in my conda environment to get the latest fixes.

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to be fixed now. I get vermillion bars when I run the code in the original question.