# Matplotlib Style Not Being Applied

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I noticed an issue that was reported here: [Matplotlib style not working in pandas bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532001/matplotlib-style-not-working-in-pandas-bar-plot)

But the user had Matplotlib 1.5. My system configuration is as below:
Python - 3.6.0
Pandas - 0.19.2
Matplotlib - 2.0.0
Seaborn - 0.7.1
Jupyter - 4.4.1

Many of the available styles on Matplotlib are not working. As an example,

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-paper')
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,7) 
df[["CHI"]].plot(kind="bar")
```

results in:
[image]
Evidently, the `seaborn-paper` style has not been applied. Is this a bug, or am I doing something incorrectly?

The data I am using is simple just one column.

```
|        | CHI |
|--------|-----|
| Red    | 4   |
| Blue   | 5   |
| Yellow | 8   |
| Green  | 7   |
| White  | 15  |
```

Edit: These are the libraries I have imported.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

Adding a video:
https://youtu.be/M5sAsKf0UUg

Comment: Have you imported seaborn? It has its own [set_style](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_style.html) function.

Comment: Yes I have imported seaborn too.

Comment: How do you know the seaborn-paper style has not been applied?

Comment: I have used it previously (about 3 days ago, on a friend's system) and the result was a black and white theme, devoid of any other color.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the [Style Sheet reference](http://matplotlib.org/examples/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html).

As can be seen there `seaborn-paper` is **not grayscale**:

[image]

You may want to use `grayscale` instead:

[image]

---

Once a style sheet has been set, it cannot simply be overwritten, since each style-sheet may have different non-overlapping settings applied.

The procedure to use a new style sheet in a notebook would be to

1. First reset all styles to the default by

   ```
   plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)
   ```
2. Then asking for the inline backend

   ```
   %matplotlib inline
   ```
3. Finally apply the new style sheet

   ```
   plt.style.use('seaborn-paper')
   ```

Here is a complete example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - it appears that I assumed 'seaborn-paper' was in black and white, because that's what I got when I ran it. Replicated it in the video I posted above.

Comment: So is this problem solved or is there still some open question?

Comment: It is open, as can be seen in the video. On applying `seaborn-paper`, the theme remains `grayscale`.